# Set system proxy automatically on connecting to wifi network on ubuntu 18.04 Bionic

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, proxy

How can ubuntu be configured to automatically set the system proxy (for apt, shell commands and for the gui programs) when it connects to a certain wifi?

Use case: Systems broadly fall into three categories
1) Never set the proxy.
2) Set proxy Once and forget about it
3) Change the proxy twice a day, every day, 6 days a week. (laptops that move from work to home)

Use case (3) was slightly irritating before 18.04, but now it's downright unusable because you have to manually edit multiple settings.

What is the most robust and simple way to automate this based on the WiFi SSID?
This implicitly also asks the question of "Is there a simple way of setting the system proxy?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with has two parts:

1) A script that is automatically executed when you connect to a network:
Paste this in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` as `05-change_proxy.sh`. It should be owned by root and executable.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Auto Proxy
# Sets the proxy based on the SSID of the wifi network
# place this script in /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/
# script must be executable and owned by root
# script needs a separate program setproxy to handle setting the proxy

# Parts the user needs to edit have a #EDIT comment next to them

# author:staticd(Sachit) 2018
# this software is released to the public domain

# See man NetworkManager for the parameters passed to a dispatcher script
# $1 is interface that changed; $2 is the specific change that occured; other information is set in the environmental variables of the script

# only run code if the script was called because a new connection was just brought "up"
if [ "$2" != "up" ]; then  
    exit 
fi


#EDIT SSIDS and the proxy settings
#echo "$CONNECTION_ID" >>/tmp/conlog
case "$CONNECTION_ID" in  # the CONNECTION_ID variable is set by the NetworkManager when it calls the script
    "MyHomeWifi")
        setproxy
        ;;
    "WorkWiFi 1" | "WorkWiFi 2")
        setproxy "proxy.company.com" "3128"
        ;;
    "OtherProxiedWifi")
        setproxy "192.168.0.1" "3128"
        ;;
#    *)                                   # any other connection is made
#        [ "$1" = "wlp3s0" ] && setproxy  # default to no proxy only if the new connection is on the wifi
#        ;;
esac
```

2) A script `setproxy` that is to be saved in `/usr/local/bin`. (also executable and owned by root)
this script can be directly called on the command line as `sudo setproxy proxy port` to set the proxy

```
#!/bin/sh

# setproxy
# Sets the proxy settings for
#    /etc/environment
#    /etc/bash.bashrc
#    /etc/apt/apt.conf
#    the gnome proxy settings for all logged in users so running programs are notified of the change


# author:staticd(Sachit) 2018
# this software is released to the public domain

setproxy_help() {
    cat << EOS
Usage: setproxy [server] [port]
Sets the system proxy (apt and environment) and updates the proxy settings of running gui programs
This program must be run as root

With -h or --help prints this message
With no arguments it disables proxying
With two arguments it sets the proxy and port

examples:
  setproxy 192.168.0.1 3128        # sets the proxy
  setproxy proxy.company.com 8080  # sets the proxy
  setproxy                         # disables the proxy
EOS
}


#EDIT this if you don't have the default session manager for example if you have a KDE or LXDE desktop
SESSION_MANAGER=gnome-session-b

unset_proxy() {
    #this function clears the proxy settings
    #delete any lines containing "proxy=" 
    sed -i "/proxy\=/d" /etc/environment
    #delete old proxy setting lines and unset any outdated environment variables inherited at login time
    sed -i "/proxy\=/d"       /etc/bash.bashrc
    echo "unset http_proxy" >>/etc/bash.bashrc
    echo "unset https_proxy">>/etc/bash.bashrc
    echo "unset ftp_proxy"  >>/etc/bash.bashrc
    echo "unset no_proxy"   >>/etc/bash.bashrc
    #delete any lines containing "Proxy"
    sed -i "/Proxy/d"   /etc/apt/apt.conf
    # ask the already running programs of logged in users to update their settings
    # programs load the get the settings in /etc/environment only when they just start
    for user in $(users | tr ' ' '\n' | sort --unique) ; do
        unset_proxy_logged_in_user "$user"
    done
}

unset_proxy_logged_in_user(){
    USER=$1
    su "$USER" << EOS
    export $(cat /proc/$(pgrep "$SESSION_MANAGER" -u "$USER")/environ|egrep -z '^DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=')
    gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'
EOS
}

set_proxy() {
    # this function sets the proxy settings for apt and the environment
    # first argument should be server, second is the port
    unset_proxy
    proxy_url='http://'"$1":"$2"
    echo $proxy_url
    # set the default environment
    echo "http_proxy=\"$proxy_url\"" >>/etc/environment
    echo "https_proxy=\"$proxy_url\"">>/etc/environment
    echo "ftp_proxy=\"$proxy_url\""  >>/etc/environment
    echo "no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1">>/etc/environment
    # set the proxy for all new terminals that are opened. (without this, new terminals that are opened may continue to inherit outdated environment variables from the state of /etc/environment file at login time)
    echo "export http_proxy=\"$proxy_url\"" >>/etc/bash.bashrc
    echo "export https_proxy=\"$proxy_url\"">>/etc/bash.bashrc
    echo "export ftp_proxy=\"$proxy_url\""  >>/etc/bash.bashrc
    echo "export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1">>/etc/bash.bashrc
    # set the apt proxy
    echo "Acquire::Http::Proxy \"$proxy_url\";"  >>/etc/apt/apt.conf
    echo "Acquire::Https::Proxy \"$proxy_url\";" >>/etc/apt/apt.conf
    echo "Acquire::Ftp::Proxy \"$proxy_url\";"   >>/etc/apt/apt.conf
    # ask the already running programs of logged in users to update their settings
    # programs load the settings in /etc/environment only when they just start
    for user in $(users | tr ' ' '\n' | sort --unique) ; do
        set_proxy_logged_in_user "$user" $1 $2
    done
}

set_proxy_logged_in_user(){
    USER=$1
    SERVER=$2
    PORT=$3
    su "$USER" << EOS
    export $(cat /proc/$(pgrep "$SESSION_MANAGER" -u "$USER")/environ|egrep -z '^DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=')
    gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
    gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host $SERVER
    gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port $PORT
    gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.https host $SERVER
    gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.https port $PORT
    gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp host $SERVER
    gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp port $PORT
    gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts "['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8' , '::1' ]"
EOS
}


# print help message
if [ $# -eq 1 ] ; then
    case $1 in
    "-h" | "--help" )
        setproxy_help  
        exit
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid argument" $1
        echo "call " $(basename $0) "-h for help"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
fi

# check if running as root
if ! [ $(id -u) = 0 ]; then
   echo "This script needs to be run as root"
   exit 1
fi

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
    unset_proxy
    exit
fi

if [ $# -eq 2 ] ; then
    set_proxy $1 $2
    exit
fi

# If the execution reached here it was called with too many arguments
echo "too many arguments"
echo "call " $(basename $0) "-h for help"
exit 1
```